# How to use multiple form types in symfony to create a single form with data class

Tags: php, symfony

Firstly, let me admit that I am an amateur in symfony forms. Any help would be really appreciated. I am not allowed to share the actual code and hence I am using some example code to demonstrate the use case.

Given below is the use case,

I have an entity called testEntity,

```
class testEntity {
    private $property1;
    private $property2;
    private $property3;

    //with setters and getters
}
```

I have a form type called formType1,

```
    class formType1 extends AbstractType {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
            $builder
                ->add('property2')
                ->add('property3)
            ;
        }

        public function buildView() {
           // Code that create view vars
        }
    }
```

And I have a form type for testEntity,

```
class testEntityType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('property1)
        ....
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => testEntity::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

formType1 is a form type with out data class and with it's own template and will be used by itself. What I want to do is to re-use formType1 in testEntityType as formType1 has the fields that map to testEntity's properties so that when submitted I could get testEntity object with the form data and I can also get formType1's view in my final form.

Controller action has this,

```
$testEntity = new testEntity();
$form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $testEntity);
```

so that when, the form submits I get $testEntity with the data from form

Apologies in advance, if I haven't framed the question well enough to be understood.

**Got this working by doing this,**

```
class testEntityType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('property1')
            ->add('formType1', formType1::class, [
                 'mapped' => false,
                 'data' => $options['data']
            ])
        ....
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => testEntity::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

Passed data via options and sett `mapped` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact your `formType1` is just a custom type.
So the only thing you have to do is to import your Type you want to use and add it in your builder just like you'll do with a non-custom Type (ChoiceType, TextType etc.).

```
use YourBundle\Type\formType1;

class testEntityType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('property1')
            ->add('formType1', formType1::class, [
               'data_class' => testEntity::class, //line edited
            ])
        ....
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => testEntity::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

PS : Watch out about the naming convention of your classes

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. If we use `formType1` as the name of the child form as you have mentioned in your update, it will error out saying there is not such method like `getFormType1()` or properties like `formType1` in `testEntity`.

Comment: Can you update your question with your controller action using this form ? What happens if you add `data_class` in your builder (see edit)

Comment: Updated the question with code in controller action. Also, by passing data_class in the builder, it still gives the same error which is as follows,
`Neither the property "formType1" nor one of the methods "getFormType1()", "formType1()", "isFormType1()", "hasFormType1()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Entity\testEntity"`
As we are passing data_class, the form is expected to have child which has  names that maps to the properties of data class and `formType1` doesn't map to any property of `testEntity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest in helping me. Got this working by passing data via options and setting `mapped` to `false`. Updated with the solution.